# Get value returned from another Window WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a grid in which the user can select rows and change the date of a row.
My problem is is that I can't figure out how to pass the value between the windows.
My first window (form1) has the grid and my second window (form2) is where I pick the date:

[image]

In the case above, the date of the selected date should be changed.

I have all the information to do the update but the only thing I'm having trouble with is passing the selected date from the second window back to the first one.

My approach is:

Form1:

```
private void btn_LaunchChangeInvoiceDate_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime UpdatedDate;
    if(gridView.SelectedRowsCount > 0 )
    {
        Form2 DatePicker = new Form2();
        DatePicker.Show();
        UpdatedDate = DateTime.Parse(DatePicker.SelectedDate);
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
 public String SelectedDate;

    public MonthPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_PickDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");           
    }
}
```

What would my method be to push `SelectedDate` to `Form1`?
My current app just gets stuck without much information...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're doing DatePicker.Show() instead of DatePicker.ShowDialog(). ShowDialog stops the code executing at that line until the form is closed. Show will just continue executing the code immediately. The result of this is that your SelectedDate is null when Form1 looks at it.

If you do not want to use ShowDialog, then you will have to use a different method of retrieving the value such as an event on Form2 for when the Pick Date button is clicked.

Side note: I do not see the need to format the date in Form2, just have the SelectedDate property be of type DateTime and Form1 can format it however it wants to instead of having to parse the string.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above you want to use ShowDialog(). Then you want to check the result from the dialog box and fetch the data you want. Here is an example using a String instead of a Date, but the principle is the same. It's a cleaner way of displaying a dialog and returning data.

Main form Form1:

```
namespace DlgExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();

            // look a good result
            if (form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // get the data and put it where you need it
                form1TextBox.Text = form2.myString;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The called dialog Form2

```
namespace DlgExample
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private String _string = string.Empty;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // get the data from the control
            _string = form2TextBox.Text;

            // DialogResult.OK result
            DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;

            // close this dialog
            this.Close();
        }

        // public property
        public String myString
        {
            get
            {
                return _string;
            }
        }
    }
}
```